# Slow form in Access due to combobox and linked sql tables

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Goal: I have two tables: 1.) Customers, 2.) Orders. I want to make a form in MS Access where the user can filter (by combobox) on the "Customer" and sees all orders of that customer in table form. When a new product is entered into the Order form, the row needs to auto populate/update the CustomerId in the Order table which was filtered by the combobox.

Real database design: Customers (5 records) and Orders table (160 records) are linked tables from a SQL Server. In the Orders table, I have only placed the CustomerID not the name, since I want to maintain the Customer table on its own and not change all records. By query in Access I search the Customer name so I can use it in the form.

Problem: When I use an unbound combobox of the table Customers the form is really slow. When I remove the join (Customers.CustomerId on Orders.CustomerId) from the query to retreive the customer name, the form works fast enough.

Question: what would be the best way to design such a simple form without losing performance.
I have created a demo databases with local tables, where the performance is perfect. However, when I change it to linked sql tables performance is decreasing.

SampleAccessFile: https://easyupload.io/a4eak3

Answer (score 0):

Well, a combo box EVEN without SQL server was always a VERY bad idea if you have say more then 100 rows. In other words, how much torture's do you want to inflict on your users? A drop down with 100s of choices is too painful, but ALSO tends to be slow anyway.

One of the first developer interview questions many software companies like Google, Microsoft etc. ask?

How big, how far, what kind of scale type of questions.

I mean, if the store is a block away, you can walk. If the store is 100 miles away, then you need to use some kind of motorized transportation, and you can't walk anymore, can you?

So, when combo choices start to exceed say 100 choices, then anything beyond that is too big, too far, and too much pain and suffering you inflict on your users.

But, WORSE YET is you also will start to encounter performance problems when you exceed say 100 rows anyway. And this advice does not really apply to just using SQL server, but even for most access applications, you want to keep the overloading of choices to the user - a combo box is  VERY poor choice when you exceed about 100 choices anyway. So, keep the how far, how big and how much in mind ALWAYS!

The next tip?

As a general rule, you want to limit the form to ONE record. I mean, say the table has 1 million rows of data. You are free to bind the form to that large linked table.

but, use the OpenForm command to ONLY load up the form with ONE reocrd. That way, then you only pull 1 row out of 1 million rows, and the form load should be near instance.

So, use this code:

```
docmd.OpenForm "frmCustomers",,,"InvoiceNum = 123434"
```

As a result, access is smart, and will ONLY PULL one record!!!! this is EVEN the case when the form is directly bound to the linked table!!!!

Now, of course you might have some sub forms etc. but we don't care.

So, in place of a combo box?

Build a search form:

Remember, users cannot edit or use or do anything UNTIL they found the record they need to work on.

In fact, in some applications users will spend their WHOLE DAY IN THAT ONE search form!!!

If they are processing invoices, or dealing with customers on the phone or whatever? The FIRST thing they will do is search!!!!!

The whole search process, and selection of a match should happen with great ease. The user SHOULD NOT have to remove his hands from the keyboard. In other words, no mouse and keyboard dance should occur. In addition, if the user makes a mistake, then re-searching, or re-trying a another search should again not require the user to use the mouse. In other words, the user should be able to re-search, and re-try and re-search with a real ease. This means that a option to "clear" the existing search should also be available, and that should also be single quick keystroke. (I use the Esc key).

Ok, so lets run down how this search is going to occur. Our example has a very small set of names to search, only 300,000 (but, it could be 3 million rows).
If our search only results in say 200 reocrds???

This means that our search will not produce any kind of noticeable load on a typical office network. If you don't start restricting the records to that form, then you are asking for trouble. Look at any software or any web site today that does searching, and you will see that these systems ASK THE USER BEFORE they try and display the results. This is so basic to any software that you use. The designers of these systems not only ask the user because it performs faster, but it also eliminates you throwing up a huge screen with a zillion fields etc, and the user asking..ok, now what? So, asking the user what they want to search for is much more user friendly, and HEY, it performs 1000's of times faster then being a lazy developer!

So, even with such a small number of names, the amount of matches you get for common names such as Smith will actually be quite large. In other words, this is human interface problem, and not one of performance. With 300,000 names, and searching for a common name like smith, we are likely to get about 2000, maybe less records.

Surely, we are not now going to force the user look trough 200 records...are we? We really need some society to prevent cruelty to users. I am amazed that the torture we developers inflict on users by thinking that a search for names can be done with a drop down combo box! Would you really want a user to troll thought 200 smiths?

So, the next obvious problem is give the user some type of drill down ability to select the sub set, and further refine the search. The simple trick here is to prompt for both the first name, and the last name. If there are only a few matches, then users can simply hit enter for the first name and cursor should now allow the arrow keys to browse through the pick list. Most of the time, a name match by last name is ok, but we still have to help for those common names. In addition, if we provide a prompt for both the Last and first name, then if you ONLY know the first name, then you can easily search via first name, and not have to "switch" to some special first name search screen.

So, we have:

Search for LastName : _______________

User hits Enter key, and then a list of matches is displayed. You cursor is now in the FirstName field. If the user chooses NOT to further refine the search, then Hitting Enter will place the cursor into the pick list. Hence we have

[image]

Search for LastName : _______________

{hit enter, or tab...match list is displayed}

Search for FirstName: _______________

The above approach is good for the typical small files you have with ms-access applications. By small, I mean in the few hundred thousand range.

But, with sql server, then even 1 million+ rows works fantastic.

We are going to search for a person named Jonah Smith. You can see above that the user only typed in Smi (the first 3 characters). However, with our good search screen that is all he needs to type. The user then hit Enter. You can see how there are 20 matches. While this file has 30+ thousands names, the only reason why we see only 20 names is that the default radio button of "this season" restricts the search to people who only took a trip this tour season. Now the user will probably type in jo in a attempt to match Jonah. Hence, the next screen show two important things.

- The matches that now starts with jo is now displayed.
- The cursor is now in the pick list. The user is free to use the arrow keys and hit Enter

so, we now have this:

[image]

At this point the user can use the down arrow once, and hit Enter key to bring up our name of Jonah Smith. I of course DO accommodate the mouse users. The little set of glasses icon REALLY SHOULD be a non graphical with the simple text of View/Edit button. While a View/Edit text button is better from a user learning and training point of view, I simply like the glasses and it is my program! Since I use the little glasses virtually everywhere in my application to bring up details, then the user only has to click on them once to discover and learn what they accomplish. In addition to the user hitting the Enter key, or clicking on the little glasses, you can also double click anywhere on the detail line. This double click is again often used and seen in applications, and thus I threw that in also.

You will also notice that there is a Add button. That means if the name you are looking for is not found, then you can easily add a new record. Since the "Add grouping" button is also Hot keyed, then Alt-A key will add a new record. This means that users can still search, and edit, or add names 100% via the keyboard.

ALSO VERY important?

We talking about human engineering here. (user habits)
If you make the search screen VERY easy to use?

Then users by habit will search FIRST!!!

I seen so many systems, where searching is a pain - users don't bother, and now you have boatloads of duplication in the system - and its the developer fault, since they made searching too hard, and thus users just enter the name or customer or whatever again!!!!

So make your search screen FRONT and center. And better yet?

Well, it not only makes your software a joy to use, but ALSO encourages users to search first.

After all, users can't do ANY work until they found the record to work on then right???

Even better?

This setup encourages good work flow. You find what you need to work on. You edit, do your work, and THEN CLOSE the form!!!

That means if 2 minutes later they phone the office back, then ANY operator of your software can now search and bring up their name.

If you load up a combo box, and other users on the system JUST added new information, then that combo box now does not have those new records!

But then again, why would you load a huge massive list into a combo box? No one would do that, right??? Not only is such a setup slow, it also not multi-user friendly.

and by having users ALWAYS by habit close the form with the ONE main record? Then you encourage them to close the form, which also means they just saved their edits. And when they close that form, they return right back to the search screen ready to do battle with the next customer or task at hand.

So, in summary:

Don't load a huge list of choices into a combo box. It is too slow, consumes too much network bandwidth, is not user friendly, and also does not really give  your applcation a nice work flow.

be it using web based search, a accounting package or anything?

provide a search form, then users can use the resulting pick list to pick a customer.

On that search form, I have that one row button to click on that launches the ONE form to the ONE record.

It is simple, and does this:

```
docmd.OpenForm "frmBooking",,,"ID = " & ME!ID
```

And now the access form loads ONE main record, and displays say this:

[image]

It really don't matter how large the database is, since the ONE main form record is filter to ONE record, and that going to load fast no matter how many rows in the system.

So, save world suffering, and save your computer bandwidth. Don't EVER load up a huge combo box list - they are too slow, not work flow friendly at all.

A combo box works for about 100 rows, and after that, you just beating your users with a club and going to cause pain and suffering.

build a great search form. Not only will users love you, your performance of the applcation will be the same with 2000 rows, or 2 million rows.

And the search code for above?

It looks like this:

```
Dim myconds    as string
Dim MySQL      as string

myconds = ""

If Len(Nz(txtSFirstName, "")) > 0 Then
   myconds = myconds & " FirstName like '" & txtSFirstName & "*'"
End if

If Len(txtSLastName) > 0 Then
     If myconds <> "" Then myconds = myconds & " and "

     myconds = myconds & "( tblMainClient.LastName like '" & txtSLastName & "*') "
End if

MySQL = "SELECT *  FROM qryMainClient WHERE " & _
        myconds & " ORDER BY LastName"

Me.tblMainClient_subform.Form.RecordSource = MySql
```

So, we simple shove the sql string into the sub form in that search page and display the results (our pick list).

Answer (score 0):

You can display the customer name in a TextBox on the orders form whose Control Source is set to

```vb
=DLookup("FirstName & ' ' & LastName", "tblCustomer", "CustomerId=" & Me!CustomerId)
```

You do not need to include the customer table in Record Source of the orders form.